# Graph API (#4) Application request limit reached | Facebook comments plugin how get all comments from application with one request

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

> Friends I know there are 2 similar questions in StackOverflow. I know that
>   this is not Facebook forums. So Before Starting to write any (bad)
>   comment, please read the question. I need help, that's why I'm writing
>   here, maybe somebody knows the answer.

I have website where I connected Facebook comment plugin to let users comment each publciation. Now I need to sync comments count to my database. I know that I can subscribe to Facebook events, but that solution do not fit my needs. 
I wrote a command in Laravel to make it. For each publication I request Graph API with this url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/$articleUrl?fields=engagement&access_token=$appId|$appSecret
```

to get that count and sync data to DB. Cause I have many publications after some requests I start to get this message

```
(#4) Application request limit reached
```

Now the question: Is there any way to avoid this limitation OR to get all publications' comments in one request?

I was trying to find solution for some 2 hours and all old similar questions in StackOverflow didn't help me, I found nothing in Graph API documentation.

Comment: There is no way to “avoid” those limits. If there was, why would Facebook have implemented them in the first place, would’ve been rather pointless then. The limit of calls you can make increases with the number of “active users” your app has though - but we don’t know if that applies in any way in your scenario. With a user instead of app token, things would still be pretty much the same. And while there is a syntax to request data from multiple objects in one go, that would still not help you here, because regarding rate limits, those would still _count_ the same as X individual calls would.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I appreciate it. I just added sleep for each request, cause that data is not important to get immediately.